# GMA 3150. Black screen before login

Tags: 12.04, 13.04, intel-graphics, login-screen, ubuntu-netbook

I tried to install Ubuntu 12.04, 13.04 and Mint 15, but I got the same bug. It's a Lanix Lt netbook with a GMA 3150 graphic card.

When I boot from the liveCD (on a USB) works perfectly. But when the installation ends and I reboot, I got a black screen after the grub. Nevertheless, I can hear the sound of the login's screen and increase the bright.

I installed the Intel's privative graphic driver (using nomodeset) but still the same thing.

When booting with `nomodeset` I can see everything, but I can't select the correct resolution (only gives me 1024x700 and 800x600) and without graphic acceleration.

I runned `lspci` command at the terminal and detects the intel driver.
There must be a problem when installing the graphic driver, I suppose. Can someone tell me what can I do?, please.

Answer (score 1):

I made a clean installation with the 12.04 and found a workaround for this:
-After the login screen's sound, I wrote my password and entered to my user (blind login).
-Waited until I was sure that the load finished and closed the lid to suspend.
-Then, I opened the lid and everything was fine, except by that the touchpad stopped working and I had to use a usb mouse.

reference: http://www.ubuntu-es.org/node/173550#.Ug7vXb-IS0w

-At this point, I had to do this: http://www.taringa.net/posts/linux/15304352/Touchpad-no-funciona-despues-de-suspender-Ubuntu.html
-Still not working but, after suspend normally using the session's menu, everything was fine, except by the black screen (violet, really)at the login.

*references in spanish